# Call a function within R.assocPath() in ramda.js

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to call a function that creates the value I want added into my json file. I'm new to functional programming so I'm not sure if this is something I should be doing or how I can accomplish this.

```
field => R.assocPath([ATTRIBUTES_KEY, XPATH_ATTRIBUTE], buildFieldXpath(domain, field, 'brfs', model._fields), field)
```

The problem is in buildFieldXpath, I want the value from that function to be placed as the value for XPATH_ATTRIBUTE. I'd like to see if there any suggestions on a way to make this work.

This is the error I get, but it is caused when I have the buildFieldXpath function in the assocPath, the returned value from buildFieldXPath, is what I want to put into my value for the field

```
C:\developer\workspace\compiler\domain-compiler\lib\domain-compiler.js:160
  return attributes.hasOwnProperty(key) ? attributes[key] : null;
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at getItemAttribute (C:\developer\workspace\compiler\domain-compiler\lib\domain-compiler.js:160:21)
    at getFieldXpath (C:\developer\workspace\compiler\domain-compiler\lib\domain-compiler.js:698:10)
    at buildFieldXpath (C:\developer\workspace\compiler\domain-compiler\lib\domain-compiler.js:724:66)
    at R.pipe.field (C:\developer\workspace\compiler\domain-compiler\lib\domain-compiler.js:109:63)
```

Comment: I think you can just call `assocPath([ATTRIBUTES_KEY, ...buildFieldXpath(domain, field, 'brfs', model._fields)], value, obj)`.  That's assuming that `buildFieldXpath` returns an array.  If it's a scalar value, then skip the `...`.

Comment: the value is I want is the actually xpath that is returned from buildFieldXpath

Comment: Then does your code above not work properly?  It looks as though it should, assuming all the variables are correct.

Comment: I'll add the stacktrace to the question. I thought this should work correctly as well, but can't seem to get around it.

Comment: You are not calling that function from within `assocPath`.  You are using it to create an argument that you will pass to `assocPath`.  The issue is within the function `buildFieldXPath`, or in one of those dependencies shown in the stack trace.  It might be clearer if you wrote `const value = buildFieldXpath(domain, field, 'brfs', model._fields), field)` followed by `assocPath([ATTRIBUTES_KEY, XPATH_ATTRIBUTE], value, field)`.  (It's not a problem to do it inline like you did, but this might help with debugging.)

Comment: Awesome thanks Scott, so the `field => assocPath.... is in an R.pipe function so it doesn't like the const value = buildFieldXPath(...) ` I'll look into the buildFieldXpath function in the meantime.